# How to configure RabbitMQ in Kubernetes for Apps to communicate

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, kubernetes, rabbitmq

I have a virtual machine with Kubernetes (minikube) installed.  I have a couple of docker images running a .net 6 web-api app.  Now I would like to setup RabbitMQ to allow the apps to talk to each other.  How do configure RabbitMQ into the environment.  Does RabbitMQ need to run in a docker container, or do I need to install it on the VM to run with Kubernetes.  Not sure how to integrate RabbitMQ into the environment so the api's can use the RabbitMQ exchange.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can install it both ways either run it as the container or run it on **VM** outside of the Kubernetes cluster.

If you will run it as the container it would be easy to manage, install and services can directly connect to it, no need to take care of firewall, port security, etc. Microservices will be able to connect to it using the service name.

If you will install it on VM and services running on **Kubernetes** you have to set up network connectivity so from K8s to VM service can connect to RabbitMQ.

You can checkout the RabbitMQ operator to install the RabbitMQ on Kubernetes : https://www.rabbitmq.com/kubernetes/operator/operator-overview.html

You can setup HA RabbitMQ on Kubernetes and the application will be easily able to connect it to.